# Make python don't undo things after an error is raised in try block

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, error-handling, try-catch

I have a python class in which I open files and read out data. If some creteria are not met, I raise an error, but before that I specify the error by giving the object an attribute: `self.Error = specification`. But since the error raising undos everything in the try block I can't access it. This happens in the `__init__` function, so the created object doesn't even exist..

Here's the necessary code:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #do something
        if this_or_that:
            self.Error = specification
            raise MyCostumError
try:
    object = MyClass()
except MyCostumError:
    print(object.Error)
```

I get: `NameError: name 'object' is not defined`

Just for clarification:
I have defined `MyCostumError`, the variable names are just for better understanding: I use good ones and they are defined and I need the clarification, because an Error can be raised in different lines.

So here's my question:
Is there something like `try/except`, but when an error is raised it does NOT undo everything. Or am I just stupid and there is a much easier method for a achieving this?

Comment: Why don't you want to put the error "specification" into the error?

Comment: This was my first try at raising Errors. I didn't know that this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are raising an exception in the initializer, you should not rely on the object to be created to get some error information to the caller. This is where you should use the exception to pass that information:

```
class MyCustomError(Exception):
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #do something
        if this_or_that:
            raise MyCustomError(specification)  # put the spec in the exception itself
try:
    object = MyClass()
except MyCustomError as e:
    print(e)  # the spec is in the exception object
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reference to an object that cannot exist. Let me explain:
If an error occurs when you try to initialise an object, that object will not be initialised. So if you try to acced to it when it is not initialised, you will get an error.

```
try:
    object = MyClass() #initialising object successful, object existing.
except: #initialising failed, object does not exist.
    print(object.Error) #nameError, since object was never created.
```

Try/except doesn't undo anything, just stops doing something if an error occurs.

Comment: If "object was never created", then why doesn't `self.Error` create a different error? Clearly `self` already has been created.

Comment: The correct way to state this is that `MyClass()` raises the exception so that `object = ` assignment never happens

Comment: Well, everything that is in a function that produces an error is undone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: So if something is printed, it gets unprinted?

Comment: In this case, if the MyClass __init__ contained something like printing or initialising variables not involved with self, they would not be undone.

Answer (score 1):

Error raising doesn't undo anything. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

As your output states, the `object is not defined`, this is because when you raise an error in the `__init__`, it is seen as the initialosor of your class failing, and this does not return an object.

---

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # do initialisation stuff

    def other_method(self):
        # do something
        if this_or_that:
            self.Error = specification
            raise MyCustomError(specification)  


object = MyClass()

try:
   object.other_method()
except MyCustomError as e:
    print(e)  

print(object.Error)
```

Comment: So if its not in the `__init__` functions my code would basically work?

Comment: Yeah! You just need an initialised class, and a reference to the `object` to get the `error` out.

Comment: @MichaelHofmann I've just added a code snippet to my answer that may be what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a beautiful solution but it should work:

```
errorcode = None

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        global errorcode
        #do something
        if this_or_that:
            errorcode = specification
            raise MyCostumError
try:
    object = MyClass()
except MyCostumError:
    print(errorcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your question I think the following should fit your use case well.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do something
        try:
            if this_or_that:
                    self.Error = specification
                    raise MyCostumError
        except MyCustomError as e:
            # Handle your custom error however you like
    
object = MyClass()
```

In the above case you should be able to mitigate the risk of instantiation failing due to custom exception/error raising failing by handling this behaviour within `MyClass.__init__` itself.

This is also a much cleaner solution in terms of keeping logic relating to instantiation of `MyClass` objects contained within the `__init__` function of the class - i.e. you won't have to worry about wrapping instantiations of this class in try/except blocks each time they are present in your code.